# How to display Highcharts legends with their corresponding chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have 3 charts in one page and I need help rendering the legends for the chart with their corresponding ones. The issue that I have is that the legends for chart 3 are showing up after chart 2 legends with chart 2, and not chart 3. What can I do to fix it?

Following are the legends that goes with chart 2:

- No Info
- Prior-trade Only
- Pre-trade Only
- Pre-trade and Prior-trade

And following are the legends that needs to go with chart 3:

- With Bid
- With Ask
- With Bid and Ask

  ```
  function set_legend() {
          legend = $('#legend');
          legend.html('');
          let listed = {};
          $.each(Highcharts.charts, function(i, chrt) {
              // Flag to avoid looping through the first chart
              if (i !== 0) {
              $.each(chrt.series, function(j, serie) {
                  let tmp_key = serie.name.replace(/[\s,-]/g, '');
                  if (!Object.keys(listed).includes(tmp_key)) {
                  legend.append(
                      '<div class="item ' + tmp_key + '"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:' +
                      serie.color +
                      '"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' +
                      serie.name +
                      '</div></div>'
                  );
                  listed[tmp_key] = [serie];
                  } else {
                  listed[tmp_key].push(serie);
                  }
              });
              }
          });

          Object.keys(listed).forEach(key => {
              // Get the legend and add a click handler
              $('#legend .' + key).click(function() {
              listed[key].forEach(serie => {
                  if (serie.visible) serie.setVisible(false);
                  else serie.setVisible(true);
              });
              });
          });
      }
  ```

**For complete example, please see the following JsFiddle link:**
https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/rsw47q86/5/

**Issue:**
[image: issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have fogotten to make the difference betwwen legend and legend2:

for chart > 7 you have to select legend2 either legend:

```
  function set_legend() {
      $('div[id^=legend]').html('');
      let listed = {};
      var legend;
      $.each(Highcharts.charts, function(i, chrt) {
          // Flag to avoid looping through the first chart
          if (i > 3) {
            legend = i > 7 ? $("#legend2") : $("#legend");

          $.each(chrt.series, function(j, serie) {
              let tmp_key = serie.name.replace(/[\s,-]/g, '');
              if (!Object.keys(listed).includes(tmp_key)) {
              legend.append(
                  '<div class="item ' + tmp_key + '"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:' +
                  serie.color +
                  '"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' +
                  serie.name +
                  '</div></div>'
              );
              listed[tmp_key] = [serie];
              } else {
              listed[tmp_key].push(serie);
              }
          });
          }
      });

      Object.keys(listed).forEach(key => {
          // Get the legend and add a click handler
          $('div[id^=legend] .' + key).click(function() {
          listed[key].forEach(serie => {
              if (serie.visible) serie.setVisible(false);
              else serie.setVisible(true);
          });
          });
      });
  }
```

dont forget to modify the css rules:

```
#legend, #legend2 { white-space: pre; margin-top: 35px; }
```

Comment: glad to help you, i have done a light modification: `i > 3 and dont forget to modify too the css rules`